# Decent KDE XML viewer?

Tags: xml, linux, kde-plasma

what's your XML viewer of choice from within KDE? Something that formats the XML decently. I've searched around but have not found anything reasonable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i just open in Kate, if formatting is an issue, filter it through `xmllint --format`.  of course i have the filter plugin active, so it's right in the menu

Comment: Very useful hint!
To format selected part of a document use:
xmllint --format -
(with trailing minus)

Answer (score 1):

(n)vi(m)

depending on your system and if you want syntax highlighting :)

Answer (score 1):

For visual editing use [Congolemerate](http://www.conglomerate.org/) or Kxmleditor.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "Decent"?

I don't work with XML much, but Firefox does a somewhat good job, for what I need.

Comment: sorry for the blurriness:) basically, just something that formats and colourises the XML reasonably. i currently also use Firefox, but was hoping to find something native to KDE and lightweight.

i see that Phil Nash asked something similar, but his question seemed specific to windows

Answer (score 0):

Just went through the same thing myself and didn't find good options for KDE.

However! Here are some other options:

- There are two Chrome Browser extensions

  1. XV (my favorite) found here: [XV at chrome app store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eeocglpgjdpaefaedpblffpeebgmgddk). It has a pre-collapsed source view (configurable depth), as well as an outline view and XPath query feature.
  2. myXMLia found here: [myXMLia at chrome app store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/igmlklkcpaicipgblfckillahieebimf).  It has a nice XML grid view like I guess some high-end viewers have.
- There is also a windows tool (with out-dated debian package from 2008), whose windows version runs fine under wine.  It includes a pre-collapsed source view, an XPath query feature, an XML diff tool, and a nice XSLT transformation tool, which is pretty cool.

  - Found here: [xmlTreeNav](http://freshmeat.net/projects/xmltreenav/)

Answer (score 0):

A quick and generic solution to view xmls cross-OS could be this [web app](http://view.xmlgrid.net/). It runs on every browser (at least they claim so). You just copy & paste the xml and click submit to display it in a tree view.